# "Pandas" error on second iteration through for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, python-docx

On the second iteration through the nested for loop I get the error:

> "File
>   "C:\Users\SmithC113\PycharmProjects\ASCII_Word\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py",
>   line 1404, in 
>       return (len(non_na) > 0 and all(x.endswith('0') for x in non_na) and SystemError: error return without exception set."

I can't figure out what is causing this error.  Any help is appreciated.

I tried dict.clear thinking maybe the dictionary was just automatically appending the data from the array, but that didn't work.  I also tried dict.update in conjunction with and without the dict.clear.  I don't understand the error so it's hard to come with a solution.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import pandas as pd  # Pandas - gives better table display results

from docx import Document  # Invokes Document command from docx
from docx.shared import Pt  # This makes it possible to dictate the font     size we are writing to the doc-x

# IMPORT ASCII CP DATA
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = askopenfilename(title="Choose Control File")  # returns the         file path as variable for future use
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=",", header=None)
r = len(data[1])  # number of rows in ASCII file (aka number of 3D points)
print('Number of CP Points imported =', r)  # This is check for now

# IMPORT ASCII BM DATA
file_pathBM = askopenfilename(title='Choose Benchmark File')  # returns the         file path as variable for future use
data_bm = pd.read_csv(file_pathBM, sep=",", header=None)
rbm = len(data_bm[1])  # number of rows in ASCII file (aka number of 3D         points)
    print('Number of BM Points imported =', rbm)  # This is check for now

# IMPORT WORD DOCUMENT
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
doc_path = askopenfilename(title="Choose Word File")  # returns the file         path as variable for future use
document = Document(doc_path)  # Imports Word Document to Modify
t = len(document.paragraphs)  # gives the number of lines in document
print('Total Number of lines =', t)  # this is a check for now
font = document.styles['Normal'].font
font.name = 'Arial'
font.size = Pt(8)
x = 0

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    data_dict = {
        'NORTHING:': data[1][x],
        'EASTING:': data[2][x],
        'ELEV:': data[3][x],
        'CSF:': data[8][x],
        'STD. DEV.:': 'N: {0}\t E: {1}\t EL: {2}'.format(data[5][x], data[6][x], data[7][x])
    }
    for k, v in data_dict.items():
        if k in paragraph.text:
            paragraph.clear()
            run = paragraph.add_run()
            run.text = k + '\t'
            run.font.bold = True
            run.font.underline = True
            run = paragraph.add_run()
            run.text = '{}'.format(v)
    x += 1
    data_dict.clear()

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    print(paragraph.text)  # Prints the text in the entire document
# document.save('test1_save.docx') #Saves as Word Document after Modification
```

In the debugger I can see that the dictionary values are overwriting like I want them to, but during the second iteration at the if statement I get the above error.  I am baffled because the data is all the same type as the first iteration, and the dictionary is a single value data [y][x].  Also, you will need pandas, python-docx, and numpy.

A snipit of the data from the ASCII File is:

1,126081.2245,12608965.8380,691.5940,CP,0.0053,0.0036,0.0006,1.0000470038
2,126327.6401,12609040.7808,692.2263,CP,0.0041,0.0043,0.0009,1.0000467574
3,126738.8659,12609037.5712,691.4403,CP,0.0043,0.0058,0.0030,1.0000464372
4,127066.6430,12608990.3587,690.2438,CP,0.0051,0.0050,0.0011,1.0000462105
5,127303.7734,12609061.0079,692.1387,CP,0.0030,0.0053,0.0029,1.0000459125

*paste it into a text file, and use it for both imports*

**The Word document format is as follows:**

> CP1
>
> DESCRIPTION: SET 5/8” X 36” IRON BAR WITH MDOT CAP IN THE NORTHWST
>   QUADRANT OF MAIN STREET AND M-51.
>
> WITNESSES:
>
> 1. FIRE HYDRANT            S42W    30.5’
> 2. LIGHT POLE          N08E    27.0’
> 3. LIGHT POLE          N47E    70.0’
> 4. CENTER OF CATCH BASIN       S45W    24.0’
>
> NORTHING:
>
> EASTING:
>
> ELEV:
>
> CSF:
>
> STD. DEV.:  N:    E:      ELEV:
>
> STATION:
>
> OFFSET:
>
> CP2
>
> DESCRIPTION: SET 5/8” X 36” IRON BAR WITH MDOT CAP IN THE SOUTHEAST
>   QUADRANT OF SYCAMORE STREET AND M-51.
>
> WITNESSES:
>
> 1. STORM MANHOLE       S73W    10.0’
> 2. CATCH BASIN         N0W 45.0’
> 3. STRAIN POLE         S53W    20.5’
> 4. FENCE CORNER            S43W    11.5’
>
> NORTHING:
>
> EASTING:
>
> ELEV:
>
> CSF:
>
> STD. DEV.:  N:    E:      ELEV:
>
> STATION:
>
> OFFSET:

Comment: About the system error, you may want to take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/8737#issuecomment-406220210)

Comment: @lincr I did see that post.  Pycharm says that the "PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL=NO" is an Illegal command.  The script also fails when I run it in a Python shell... I am thinking it has to do something within Pandas